# Store a java method in a java element variable compilationunit eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I need to store in a `IJavaElement` variable a method. I have the file path where the method is implemented and the header of the method.

That is what I have:

```java
IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor =IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
ICompilationUnit root = (ICompilationUnit) EditorUtility.getEditorInputJavaElement(editor, false);
```

regards.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you are trying to change source code (adding a variable to a method), this should be a good place to start: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_manip.htm.